# tcp_error for HTTP Post to Restful web Services

Tags: .net, ios, wcf, tcp, windows-server-2008

I am Uploading videos from mobile client to restful web services via HTTP post binary stream Upload.
I am successfully able to upload videos  with 3-4 seconds of length. But videos that are bigger than that or large videos get me this error from the server.

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
For assistance, contact Customer Support

I don't think there is any problem with application running as I was successful to Upload small videos.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 
`<system.web> <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="500000000"/> </system.web>` fixed the issue! –

Answer (score 0):

In order not to repeat same answer please check the following link on stackoverflow: [wcf tcp async streamed is possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206201/wcf-tcp-async-streamed-is-possible/11213674#11213674).

I will point out some obvious things: you have to use stream mode when you want to upload large files, you have to increase your timeout value.

Please take a look at [Large Data & Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)
and at [How to: Enable Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)

You will find all details to you are in need of there.